# How to match lines where a variable is found somewhere between two characters with grep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to output all lines from a file where a BASH variable, `$a` is found somewhere between the letters "A" and "Z", also on the same line.

```
A the cat went to the river Z
The A cat then Z swam to the lake.
Then the cat A ate Z some fish.
```

If `$a` were set to "cat", then only these lines would be output, because "cat" is found between the two characters on those lines:

```
A the cat went to the river Z
The A cat then Z swam to the lake.
```

If `$a` were set to "then", then only this line would be output, because "then" is found between the two characters:

```
The A cat then Z swam to the lake.
```

I have tried these, but none have worked:

```
grep "A*[$a]+*Z" file.txt

grep "A(.*)[$a]+(.)Z" file.txt

grep "[A]+*[$a]+*[Z]+" file.txt
```

How can I match lines where a variable is found somewhere between two characters with `grep` or a similar BASH tool?

Comment: Why are you putting it in brackets? What do you think brackets mean in regexp? Why do so many people get brackets wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
grep "A.*$a.*Z" file.txt
```

This assumes that `$a` doesn't contain any characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

All your attempts use `[$a]`, which is totally wrong. `[chars]` matches a *single* character that's any one of the `chars` inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following command :

```
egrep  "\b(A)\b.*[\$a].*\b(Z)\b" * --color
```

This will not work in below text :

```
A the cat went $a to the river Z and A goes to $a for Z reason.
```

This regex gives you `A the cat went $a to the river Z and A goes to $a for Z` as output.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution

```
awk '$0~"A.*"x".*"Z' x=$a file
A the cat went to the river Z
The A cat then Z swam to the lake.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use grep or egrep.

```
grep "$a" filename.txt
```

or if I am understanding properly then you want to make sure that there is at least one character on each side then this would be better

```
egrep ".+$a.+" filename.txt
```

or

```
grep -P ".+$a.+" filename.txt
```